# cakephp 3 find query without limit for csv export

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to query all records in my table for csv export. Normally limit the results to 20-25 is good with pagination, but in this case I want get rid of the limit call what is automatically added to my query.

How to avoid the automatic limit call?

Comment: can you share your query!

Comment: It is somethinglike this: `$query = $this->Contacts->find()`

Comment: you didn't use the paginator, why the query result you are getting  with limit?